# LogonUserEx успешно аутентифицирует пользователя при некорректном домене

Tags: windows, winapi

Ситуация следующего характера:

Имеется удаленная машина с учетной записью tyalymov\Administrator и паролем pass_1.

Имеется хостовая машина, с аутентифицирующаяся на удаленной машине, используя LogonUserEx. Заметил непонятное поведение, а именно:
Если задать:

1. Правильное имя пользователя (Administrator)
2. Неправильный домен (lol.kek)
3. Правильный пароль (pass_1)

То аутентификация проходит успешно. Пример вызова:

```
HANDLE hToken = NULL;

if (!LogonUserExW("Administrator", 
                  "lol.kek", 
                  "pass_1", 
                  LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, 
                  LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, 
                  &hToken, 
                  NULL, 
                  NULL, 
                  NULL, 
                  NULL))
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to logon user");
```

И все дальнейшее взаимодействие с удаленной машиной проходит корректно.

Вопрос: Каким образом возможно подобное поведение?

Comment: Так если Windows проверяет сведения локальной У/З, то по логике процесса проверки ей плевать на полученное имя домена. Главное это %username% + %password%

Comment: А не подскажете, где что-то подобное в документации может быть написано? MSDN, к сожалению, мне результата не дал

Comment: Это из практики. Я подозреваю, что при проверке учетных данных в SAM доменное имя не передается. Дело в том, что оно может иметь произвольные значения: **~**, **.**,  **%IP_address%**, **127.0.0.1**, **%hostanme** и т.п. Возможно, это связано с древним механизмом проверки учетных сведений метода **NTLM**. Могу лишь дать ссылки на эту [статью](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/credentials-processes-in-windows-authentication) и об **[NTLM](https://support.microsoft.com/az-latn-az/help/102716/ntlm-user-authentication-in-windows)**